# Exclude certain output classes during training of convolutional neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a large data set of 2D objects which I want to classify. I have set up a 2D convolutional neural network using keras and everything works acceptably.

However, at the moment I do not use all available prior information, specifically each input object can only belong to a small subsets of all output classes. However, this is different for each object, meaning I cannot simply train multiple networks.

Therefore, is there a way to add this information to the neural network, i.e. for each object exclude certain output classes during training and testing?

Comment: It will be helpful if you could provide a gist of the information you need to give to the neural network along with the image.

Comment: What is total number of classes, number of subsets and number of classes belonging to each subset? Also please add more detailed explanation of what you are doing with some examples and your current network architecture.